# pyqt5 qtextdocument align from right to left and export to pdf?

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, qt5, python-docx

i am working on pyqt5 project and i need to export tableview to pdf or docx.

1. for exporting as pdf it's working but i need to set alignment from
   right o left, also i have tried the html table but i couldn't align
   from right to left.
2. when i tried to export as docx it's not fully working sometimes i get
   the last row and sometimes i get iteration error.
   [image]

code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5 import QtPrintSupport as printSupport
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION
import xlsxwriter
import sys
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Arabic, QLocale.Libya))
        
        self.printer = printSupport.QPrinter()
        # Configure defaults:
        self.printer.setOrientation(printSupport.QPrinter.Portrait)
        self.printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPageSize(QtGui.QPageSize.A4))
        pageSizeDictionary = {"a2": QPrinter.A2, "a3": QPrinter.A3, "a4": QPrinter.A4}
        # self.printer.setPageSize(pageSizeDictionary.get(self.size.lower(), QPrinter.A4))
        self.printer.setPageMargins(15, 15, 15, 15, QPrinter.Millimeter)
        
        self.dpi = 72
        self.documentWidth = 8.5 * self.dpi
        self.documentHeight = 11 * self.dpi
        
        
        self.database()
        self.query = QSqlQuery()
        self.queryModel = QSqlQueryModel()
        self.productTableView = QTableView()
       
        
        self.printPushButton = QPushButton('print table', self)
        self.printPushButton.clicked.connect(self.printTableView)
        
        self.printPreviewPushButton = QPushButton('print preview', self)
        self.printPreviewPushButton.clicked.connect(self.printPreviewTableView) 
        
        
        self.exportAsDOCXPushButton = QPushButton('export as docx', self)
        self.exportAsDOCXPushButton.clicked.connect(self.exportAsDOCX)
        
        self.exportAsEXCELPushButton = QPushButton('export as excel', self)
        self.exportAsEXCELPushButton.clicked.connect(self.exportAsExcel)
        
        self.insertToDatabasePushButton = QPushButton('insert data to database', self)
        self.insertToDatabasePushButton.clicked.connect(self.insertToDatabase) 
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.insertToDatabasePushButton, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.productTableView, 1, 0)
        
        
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.printPushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.printPreviewPushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.exportAsDOCXPushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.exportAsEXCELPushButton)
        
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout,2,0)
        
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        
        self.productsTableView()
        
      
    def productsTableView(self):
        sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM product '
        self.queryModel.setQuery(sqlQuery)
        self.productTableView.setModel(self.queryModel)
        self.queryModel.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, 'رقم المنتج')
        self.queryModel.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, 'اسم المنتج')
        self.queryModel.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, 'الكمية')
        self.productTableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.productTableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.productTableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    def paintRequest(self,printer):
        model = self.productTableView.model()
        ##########
        tableFormat = QtGui.QTextTableFormat()
        tableFormat.setHeaderRowCount(1)
        tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
        tableFormat.setCellPadding(2.0)
        tableFormat.setCellSpacing(2.0)
        tableFormat.setWidth(
            QtGui.QTextLength(QtGui.QTextLength.PercentageLength, 100))
        ##########
        textOption = QtGui.QTextOption()
        textOption.setTextDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        textOption.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignHCenter)
        ##########
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        document.setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(self.documentWidth, self.documentHeight))
        document.setDefaultFont(QtGui.QFont("Console  , Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 16))
        document.setDefaultStyleSheet('body{ Background-color: red}')
        document.setDefaultTextOption(textOption)
        document.setDocumentMargin(30.0)
        document.setDefaultTextOption(textOption)
        
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
        # charFormat = cursor.charFormat()
        # charFormat.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI Light", 28))
        table = cursor.insertTable(
            model.rowCount(), model.columnCount(), tableFormat)
        for row in range(table.rows()):
            for column in range(table.columns()):
                index = model.index(row, column)
                cursor.insertText(str(model.data(index)))
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)

        document.print_(printer)    
    def printTableView(self):
        dialog = printSupport.QPrintDialog(self.printer, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            self.paintRequest(dialog.printer())
    def printPreviewTableView(self):
        dialog = printSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.paintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
    QPushButton {padding:10px;font-size:16px;font-weight: 400;}
    QTableView{
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-family: Console  , Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
    QTableView::item 
{
border:1px solid #999;
    color: #000;
      text-align: center;
}QHeaderView::section{border:1px solid #999;font-family: Console  , Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;}
    """)
    window = Window()
    window.setFixedWidth(500)
    window.setFixedHeight(300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. Please try to reduce your code to a [mre]. 2. Try to [`setTextDirection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextoption.html#setTextDirection) of the document's `defaultTextOption()` and set it back to the document. 3. If it still doesn't work, you can just cycle columns in reverse order: `for column in range(table.columns() - 1, -1, -1):`.

Comment: @musicamante  setTextDirection() is not working

Comment: I didn't tell you to remove everything else, but to make a MRE. Now your code is not reproducible as it's missing *important* parts. I also specifically told you that `setTextDirection` is a function of the text option, not of the document. I put two links in the previous comment, you're expected to read them.

Comment: @musicamantemy bad i've tested it on other code and i forget that , any way its still the same. i have thought about reversing the loop but i didn't think its gonna work

Comment: please try to do more efforts in providing a simple, short and *ready* to be reproducible code. Just create a basic table (QTableView with QStandardItemModel, or even a QTableWidget) and use that, the whole database related part is completely irrelevant for the question and forces us to make deep modifications to your code. We should focus on your problem, not on recreating it: we should be able to copy, paste and run it. Besides, you say "I didn't think it's gonna work": does it mean that you tried and it didn't work, or that you *just thought* about it but you didn't actually try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @musicamante **just cycle columns in reverse order**
[image]

```
for row in range(table.rows()):
            for column in range(table.columns()- 1, -1, -1):
                index = model.index(row, column)
                cursor.insertText(str(model.data(index)))
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
```